# how can I override a key value in ansible arrays without destroying the array

Tags: arrays, variables, ansible

I'm looking for a way to override a specific key in my array without overriding the entire array.

Example:

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: hostgroup
  vars:
    program:
      name: customname
      option1: customoption
```

Inventory:

```
program:
  name: groupname
  option2: group
```

Defaults/main

```
program:
  name: defaultname
  option1: default
  option2: default
  option3: default
```

I'm expecting these values to override as such:

```
program:
  name: customname
  option1: customoption
  option2: group
  option3: default
```

However, my actual values are:

```
program:
  name: customname
  option1: customoption
```

Source https://gist.github.com/JakeDEvans/ed13514e6d3614c3381a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Ansible 1.9.4, but it is possible in 2.0 as vars become hashes.

To combine hashes, use the filter combine:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html

```
{{ program|combine(program_inventory|combine(program_playbook)) }}
```

Comment: Worth to mention, it is possible to use the `combine` filter to generate a new hash. But it is not possible to store this combined hash with the name of one of the hashes it was combined from. It has to be stored as a new variable. So the expected behavior you described in your question is not possible in any version of Ansible.

Comment: This worked as I used it in a jinja templates to take an array and convert it to a yaml configuration file combining variables in these places.

Comment: Sure, that works. But solving your problem and answering the question are two different things. The correct answer to your above question still is: It's not possible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming defaults_main.yml is really a  role defaults variable file (e.g. roles/role_name/defaults/main.yml) and the "actual values" are what you're seeing inside the role.

Another option would be to template out the program struct in your play definition.  For example you would have:

```
- hosts: hostgroup
  vars:
    program:
      name: customname
      option1: customoption
      option2: "{{ program_inv.option2 | default('some_value') }}"
      option3: "{{ program_role.option3 | default('other_value') }}"
  roles:
  .......
```

where program_inv is defined in a host_var or group_var file and program_role is defined in the role_name/defaults/main.yml.  This way you can at least run your role with the expected values in one dict.

EDIT: added some defaults but as you point out....still messy

Comment: Where's the default vars, it gets really messy this way.

Comment: I may want all options default or custom or a mix, or both or neither